Cloudflare Speedtest local JavaScript version doesn't work
I'm a software developer, but I'm not very experienced with JavaScript. I'm trying to get a JavaScript local version of Cloudflare speedtest to run locally on a server.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04
I pulled the latest Cloudflare Speedtest:
https://github.com/cloudflare/speedtest
I updated my version of node to the latest (version 20)
Per the README:
I added the speedtest package:
npm i @cloudflare/speedtest

I ran the build command and it created the /dist directory.
I created speedtest.js in the top-level project directory with the following lines:
import SpeedTest from '@cloudflare/speedtest';
new SpeedTest().onFinish = results => console.log(results.getSummary());

When I run:
node speedtest.js

I get nothing but errors:
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=0: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?during=download&bytes=0: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=100000: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=0: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=100000: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')
Error fetching https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?during=download&bytes=0: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transferSize')


The Cloudflare speed test project documentation indicatea that this library relies on a browser API

The module performs test requests against the Cloudflare edge network and relies on the PerformanceResourceTiming browser api to extract timing results.

However, you are attempting to execute the code from a NodeJS environment, which run on a server, not a browser. This indicate that the API this library needs might not be available in the Node JS environment.
Try to run your code in a browser environment, by adding it to a JavaScript project that support modules loading and it should work.
